# In angular, simple solution to display validation messages on focus event while using valueChange method in reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

while using this code:

`firstNameControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => this.setFirstNameMessage(firstNameControl));`

The validation message is only displayed if the value in the input box changes as valueChanges method only watches value change in the input box.
I want to display the message on focus events also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the

> Pristine property or touched property

Something like this

```
firstNameControl.pristine
```

Or

```
firstNameControl.touched
```

This will return a Boolean and based on that you can show your message.

Comment: I already tried this code
`
if(!firstNameControl.pristine){
            this.setFirstNameMessage(firstNameControl);
        }
`
But I am doing all this in ngOnInit method, pristine is a property not an event that's why it does not get fired on focus.

Comment: Did you try without the ! Operator, as pristine will be true until the value is not changed.